# `global` name not defined error when using class variables

Tags: python, class, global

For some reason I'm getting a `global name is not defined` error here.  The issue lies in the `addClient` method where I am incrementing my global variable `joinID`. It throws me an error  `NameError: global name 'joinID' is not defined`.  What am I doing wrong?

```
class Chatroom:
    clients = []
    joinID = 0

    def __init__(self,name,refNum):
        self.refNum = refNum
        self.name = name

    def addClient(self,clientName):
        global clients
        global joinID
        joinID = joinID+1
        clients.append(clientName, joinID)

    def removeClient(self, clientName, joinID):
        global clients
        clients.remove(clientName, joinID)
```

Comment: Your indentation looks broken. Also, are you aware of the difference between "x" and "self.x"?

Comment: Quite simply, joinID is not defined. Nowhere is there a joinID variable declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the variables outside the class

```
joinID=0
clients=[]
class Chatroom:
    def __init__(self,name,refNum):
```

Comment: or use the `self.` prefix to look up the variables via the instance, or `Chatroom.` prefix to access them via the class.

Answer (score 4):

In a method from a class is bether to use a instance attribute or a class atribute. In this case you are using a class atribute.

```
class Chatroom:
    clients=[]
    joinID=0

    def __init__(self,name,refNum):
        self.refNum=refNum
        self.name=name

    def addClient(self,clientName):
        self.joinID=self.joinID+1
        self.clients.append((clientName,self.joinID))

    def removeClient(self,clientName,joinID):
        self.clients.remove((clientName,joinID))
```

If you wan´t to use global, you must declare the variable in the global scope:

```
joinId=0
clients=[]
class Chatroom:

    def __init__(self,name,refNum):
        self.refNum=refNum
        self.name=name

    def addClient(self,clientName):
        global joinID
        global clients
        joinID=joinID+1
        clients.append((clientName,joinID))

    def removeClient(self,clientName,joinID):
        global clients
        clients.remove((clientName,joinID))
```